# Java use SecureRandom with SunPKCS11 provider

Tags: java, pkcs#11, secure-random

I would like to use my PKCS#11 enabled device as a source of SecureRandom.

So I have done the following:

```
Provider pkcs11provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11config);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11provider);

byte[] rb = new byte[100];
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11provider);
sr.nextBytes(rb);
```

And I always get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-HSM
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:101)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:218)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance(SecureRandom.java:383)
```

What I am doing wrong? According JDK PKCS#11 Reference Guide `"PKCS11"` should be supported algorithm for `SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PKCS11" doesn't sound like an algorithm name. It is the provider name. A provider can have their own algorithm names for specific crypto operations. To see what all algorithms they have, you can run this code snippet to see them.

```
Set<Provider.Service> services = pkcs11provider.getServices();

services.forEach(service ->
{
    // System.out.println(service.getType()); // --> Look for 'SecureRandom' type
    System.out.println(service.getAlgorithm());
});
```

Look for 'SecureRandom' type, and that's the algorithm you have to pass in as the first argument in `SecureRandom.getInstance(.., ..)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to that but `services` is `null`. I am not sure why...

Comment: Look like I had a wrong slot configuration. After changed it, `services` are listed and everything is working. Algorithm name is really `PKCS11` and `SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11provider);` is working. Thank you.